# need help to store many documents from a java web app

Tags: java, file, storage

i have a little issue. I hava to generate thousands of files from a web application. I will then put them into a zip send it by mail and delete them. I was thinking about storing them on the jboss server, but i'm not a big fan of this solution.

any idea of a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you send the files as an attachment, the files are stored on the mail server and there's no need to store them anywhere else. On the other hand, you might run into size limitations. If your files are too big to be directly attached to an email, you might consider storage services like AWS S3.

Comment: i'm not allowed to directly send it by mail, or use any "cloud storage" only local storage. But i don't find how to acces shared harddrive

Comment: Accessing a shared harddrive should work just like accessing a local harddrive, you just need to set up a network share.